# Why am I unable to get any of the textillate.js animations to work except for the simple slide-in effect?

Tags: javascript, cdn

I'm a noob, and I'm trying to get textillate.js up and running on a website of mine, but all I can get it to produce is a basic slide-in effect.  Some of the animations won't work at all.  I've read several answers to similar questions on this site, and can gather that it has something to do with my reference to a CDN for animate.css, but I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong.   Below is some simple markup just to display the problem I'm having.  Thank you very much for helping me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.js"
  integrity="sha256-H+K7U5CnXl1h5ywQfKtSj8PCmoN9aaq30gDh27Xc0jk="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.css" integrity="sha512-phGxLIsvHFArdI7IyLjv14dchvbVkEDaH95efvAae/y2exeWBQCQDpNFbOTdV1p4/pIa/XtbuDCnfhDEIXhvGQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lettering.js/0.7.0/jquery.lettering.js" integrity="sha512-f+oBYjKYemdim4hxvBI29tx1aphY5ffbTlSyN+B1u8YEOAarGu4rBJ++cVzedldrScbJ1Po/rArrrgAFpOXcvg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textillate/0.4.0/jquery.textillate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/textEffects.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body style="background-color:black;color:white;">
        
        <h1 class="desc">This is some H1 text</h1>
        <p class="try">This is a longer paragraph text.  I would really like to know why it isn't working</p>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is the Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    const myName = $('.desc');
    const foot = $('.try');
    console.log("The script is recognized");
    myName.textillate({
        in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' },
        loop: true,
        out: { effect: 'hinge' },
        delayScale: 1,
        delay: 150,
        });


foot.textillate({
    
    in: { effect: 'fadeInRight' }, 
loop: true,
        out: { effect: 'rollOut' },
        delayScale: 1,
        delay: 150,
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by, instead of using the CDN link referred to on the animate.css website, I went here https://cdnjs.com/libraries/animate.css, where all previous versions, and 4 different versions of the same CDN (confusing!) are offered.  This was the link that worked for me:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.compat.css